# Where did the dust go?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

After the <s>Snappening</s> "Decimation" took place, people were turned to dust.

[image: character gets turned into dust]

Did the Handy Vac and funeral urn industries experience their greatest year ever, or did the dust literally evaporate into thin air?

Comment: I think there is a little bit of both honestly, but more of the dust fully disappearing than the alternative. In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tq3Jtoi-BUM) starting about 1:30 Bucky appears to leave a residue on the ground, but pretty much everybody else seems to disappear without a trace... I lean more to no evidence left behind and blame Bucky as a trick from the camera angle...

Comment: Decimation? Come come. That's [understating things by forty percentage points](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decimation).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - "*(generally) The killing or destruction of any large portion of a population.*" Might I suggest that you don't look up the words "irony" or "literally", since those don't mean what you think they mean either.

Comment: Compromise where you can. Where you can't, don't. Even if everyone is telling you that something wrong is something right. Even if the whole world is telling you to move, it is your duty to plant yourself like a tree, look them in the eye, and say 'No, that's not what decimation means, you illiterate gadabouts'.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite up to Valorum to confirm, but I thought this referred to [Decimation being the snap's official name](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/100276/63559). Of course, that doesn't mean the writers didn't goof themselves :-)

Comment: @Jenayah: if it's official, then alrighty; although zero points to the half that survived for using grief as an excuse not to check a dictionary. I'd be 50/50 on it until that term's used in a movie or TV show though. Maybe *Agents* or *Far From Home* will do that.

Comment: @Jenayah - It is indeed the official term for what happened. That being said, I hope no-one downvoted out of a misguided sense of trying to protect the English language from itself.

Answer (score 2):

People get turned to very fine level dust.

Eventually it just flows away with the wind, just like the normal dust that we encounter every day.

The video demonstrates this exactly, especially in cases like Fury, Hill.

In Fury's case, the inter-galactic pager is lying on the street, with not even the slightest hint of the "dust" anywhere on or near it.

Even in Endgame,

> Tony's snap dusts the Leviathans, and we do not see mounds of dust lying around there. Fairly certain that a Leviathan sized heap of dust would not go by unnoticed.

Comment: But is there any residue, is the question...

Comment: @Valorum "In Fury's case, the inter-galactic pager is lying on the street, with not even the slightest hint of the "dust" anywhere on or near it.", is the answer. And also *in* the answer :D

Comment: Sure, but did the dust just blow away or did it **disappear entirely**.

Comment: Also, did we see anyone dusted while inside? Relying on the wind is fine for people outside, but I wonder what happened to anyone in a building, would the dust just fall to the ground, or was the drifting away and seemingly dispersing part of the effect of the snap itself.

Comment: @Valorum The Fury scene would indicate that it disappeared entirely. It can't be windy everywhere around the world, but the dusted vanish without any trace. The dust is temporary.

Comment: @Stark07 - The dust from Fury blows away off screen and is really no indication of anything